# How to make the images from the bootstrap cards clickable on your index pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using the Bootstrap cards for my index page for my app but wasn't really liking the event details button, I feel it's more modern to just click on the image.

I found SOF articles pointing to how to use clickable images if the image was local and/or hosted somewhere online, but nothing that pointed to using images that are already a part of your database.

The code I had before was:

```
 <% if artist.avatar.attached? %>
       <%= image_tag artist.avatar, class: "even-size-artist" %>
    <% else %>
       <img src=<%= "https://dancewise.s3.amazonaws.com/misc-images/Blank+Avatar.png" %> class="even-size-artist">
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that I found that will give you the option to have the top image clickable to the appropriate record is as follows:

```
<% if artist.avatar.attached? %>
       <%= link_to image_tag(artist.avatar, class: "card-img-top artist-img").html_safe, artist %>
    <% else %>
       <img src=<%= "https://dancewise.s3.amazonaws.com/misc-images/Blank+Avatar.png" %> class="card-img-top artist-img">
    <% end %>
```

Hopefully, this helps someone else out there learning RoR!